# Apache Drill Supports Stored Procedure & Function

Tags: apache-drill

I want to know whether Apache Drill Supports Stored Procedure and Functions or not.? If Yes Please give some example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use built in functions :

- **Math and Trig:**
  functions  like `ABS(x)`,
  `CEIL(x)`,
  `CEILING(x)`,
  `DEGREES(x)`,
  `EXP(x)`,
  `FLOOR(x)`,
  `LOG(x)` & many more. Check [docs](https://drill.apache.org/docs/math-and-trig/).

  Example:

  ```
   SELECT ABS(`integer`) FROM dfs.`/Users/drill/input2.json`;
  ```
- **Data Type Conversion:**
  functions  like `CAST`
  `CONVERT_TO` and `CONVERT_FROM`, etc. Check [docs](https://drill.apache.org/docs/data-type-conversion/).

  Example:

  ```
  SELECT CAST('1' as DECIMAL(28, 2)) FROM (VALUES(1));
  ```
- **Date/Time Functions and Arithmetic:**
  functions  like `CURRENT_TIME TIME`, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, `DATE_ADD`, etc. Check [docs](https://drill.apache.org/docs/date-time-functions-and-arithmetic/).

  Example:

  ```
  SELECT DATE_ADD(date '2015-05-15', 2) FROM (VALUES(1));
  ```
- **String Manipulation:**
  functions  like `CONCAT`, `ILIKE`, `INITCAP`, `LENGTH`, etc. Check [docs](https://drill.apache.org/docs/string-manipulation/).

  Example:

  ```
  SELECT CHAR_LENGTH('Drill rocks') FROM (VALUES(1));
  ```
- **Aggregate and Aggregate Statistical:**
  functions  like `AVG(expression)`, `MAX(expression)`, `COUNT(*)`, etc. Check [docs](https://drill.apache.org/docs/aggregate-and-aggregate-statistical/).

  Example:

  ```
  SELECT AVG(ALL salary) FROM cp.`employee.json` WHERE employee_id IN (1139, 1140, 1141);
  ```
- **Functions for Handling Nulls:**
  `COALESCE` & `NULLIF`. Check [docs](https://drill.apache.org/docs/functions-for-handling-nulls/).

  Example:

  ```
  SELECT NULLIF(d9, d18) FROM alltypes limit 1;
  ```

**SQL Window Functions** are also supported. Check [Details](https://drill.apache.org/docs/sql-window-functions-introduction/).

**Nested Data Functions** are there to FLATTEN, Find Repeated counts,etc. Check [Details](https://drill.apache.org/docs/nested-data-functions/).

**Query Directory Functions** like `MAXDIR`, `MINDIR`. Check [Details](https://drill.apache.org/docs/query-directory-functions/).

Apart from that, you can **develop your own function**. 
Check [Tutorials](https://drill.apache.org/docs/tutorial-develop-a-simple-function/).

Comment: :- What about Stored Procedure..?

Comment: I guess not yet. There is an open issue for that: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-4222